# Cannot stage or add my directory + files

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to add my entire project directory to my github repo, but am unable to stage them (let along push them to the repo). This is what I have done so far.

```
cd masterfolder
git init
mkdir projectfolder
//add all my files + whatnot
git add projectfolder
git commit -m "this is my project"
git remote add origin https://github.com/myusername/myrepo.git
git push origin master
```

When I check my repo online, my files have not been committed.

I checked the status using `git status -s` and it turns out my files have not even been staged. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I restarted my machine and checked `git status` again. It looks like my folder was staged, but when I try

```
git push origin master
```

I get

```
Everything up to date
```

My repo online does not contain any of the files though. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

After running `git commit` I get to a screen that lists all of the staged files but I cannot run any commands from here. Please help.

Comment: What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: Do you have a .gitignore file sitting anywhere? Before you commit but after you add, you should do 'git status -s' and that will show staged files. Once you commit you won't see them from that command.

Comment: @edhedges-- please see the update above

Comment: @Roger--I do not have a .gitignore file anywhere. When I do `git status -s` it shows my staged files, but after I push them to my repo I do not see the changes online. I described it in the update above

Comment: After you've run `git add projectfolder` and `git commit -m "message"`, what's the output of `git log --oneline` on the *local* repository? You should see the commit adding the files to the repository, which would indicate the issue is to do with pushing changes from `local` to `github`, and not with adding to the local repository.

Comment: @simont--once i execute `git commit` i get to another screen where I'm not sure what to do. I can't run any commands from it. please help.

Comment: what do you get for git remote -v

Comment: `once i execute git commit i get to another screen where I'm not sure what to do. I can't run any commands from it.` If you're doing `git commit` instead of `git commit -m "commit message"`, git will take you to a terminal-based text editor (vim or nano, probably) where git wants you to author a commit message, save the file, and quit the editor. Only then will the commit be final.

Comment: @codeninja Leave a space after `@<name>` so that the user gets notified of the comment. `@<name>--` doesn't notify me that you've responded to the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> git commit -m "this is my project"
>
> I checked the status using git status -s and it turns out my files have not even been staged. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

The files *were* staged to the `staging index`, but then you **committed** them with `git commit`. This **removes** them from the `staging index`, and adds them to the repository in a commit.

As others have mentioned, you sound like you're getting an editor when you run `git commit` without `-m`. There are two probabilities:

1. vi or vim. To check: when you get in (`git commit`), you **won't be able to type anything**. Press `i`, and down the bottom left it should say something like `--INSERT--`. The steps to write in `vi` or `vim:

   > 1. Press 'i' to get into "INSERT" mode.
   > 2. Write your commit message.
   > 3. Press "ESC" to get *out* of INSERT mode.
   > 4. Type:  ':wq', **including the full-colon**. The 'w' means "write" (or "save"), the 'q' means "quit".
2. nano. To check: down the bottom of the screen there's a bunch of things like "^G Get Help", "^O Write Out", etc. To use Nano: write a commit message, then press "^O" to save, "^X" to quit. (**NOTE**: The '^' symbol denotes a CTRL key. Press 'CTRL+O' when it says "^O", etc).

> I restarted my machine and checked git status again. It looks like my folder was staged, but when I try: `git push origin master`...

You cannot `git push` changes from the *staging index* to a remote repository. The *staging index* is for building *commits* which you finalize and add to the repository using `git commit`. Look at the below picture [taken from http://git-scm.org], and [read the Pro-Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics), which **will** give you a great understanding of how `git` works.

[image: Git staging areas]

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658195/simple-sequence-of-git-commands/10659298#10659298) goes into a little more detail about the staging areas and `git add`, `git commit` etc.

Comment: great answer, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The screen you're getting into is probably a text-editor. If you're on unix/mac, it might be Vi(m).

Try to press `i`, and then enter some text. Then `ESC` and then `:wq`. It will write the commit message.

Comment: +1. I think it is the editor, too. In case your editor turns out to be nano instead, you can look at http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/ for help in how to write your commit message and exit back to the terminal.

Comment: That's what I thought also, until I saw that he wrote: `//add all my files + whatnot`

Answer (score -1):

You can't commit an empty directory. You have to create a file inside `projectfolder` and then add it. If you don't want to add any new files, you can just place a `.gitignore` file:

```
touch projectfolder/.gitignore
git add projectfolder/.gitignore
git commit # Continue as before
```

Comment: See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository

Comment: That's what I thought also, until I saw that he wrote: `//add all my files + whatnot`, so he added some files in the dir.

Comment: Whoops. I completely failed to notice that. Seemed at the time like a classic empty directory problem.