# cannot see committed changes in repo

Tags: github

I have staged my files like this

```
git add mydir
git add mydir/myfile
```

and then pushed them to my repo

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/usename/myrepo.git
git push origin master
```

When I look at `git status -s` it says my files have been added, but I cannot see them in my actual repository. Does anyone know whats going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have **not** "added" your files to the *repository*, only to the *staging index*.

You need to `git commit` to get your changes from the `staging index` to the `repository`.

`git status` shows you the status of the *working tree* and *staging index*. `git log` shows you the status of the *history* - in other words, `git log` will show you *what's been committed to the repository*.

As an example, see this `git status` output:

```
git status               
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   Game.py
#
```

In this case, we can see that the *changes to be committed* involve `Game.py`. Note that these changes haven't yet been added to the repository - they're just staged, ready to be committed, as the `git status` says.

The next step is to commit these changes we've prepared in the `staging index` and add them to the repository. `git commit` is the command to do this.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658195/simple-sequence-of-git-commands/10659298#10659298), as well as the linked [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics), have some excellent reading which will help you understand the setup and steps in committing to a `git` repository.

> I cannot see them in my actual repository.

What do you mean by "actual" repository? I am presuming you mean you can't see a *local commit*, but there may be some confusion about the repositories you're using.

You're using *two* repositories, one `local` and one `remote`. The `remote` repository is, in your case, on GitHub. You do your work *locally*, then `git push` to *remote*.

### First, local changes and commits

So the steps to get your code changes into the `local` repository are as follows:

1. **Make changes in your `working directory`**. This is most often writing some code.
2. **Build a `commit` by staging changes**. This is done using `git add`.
3. **"Save" the commit you've built into the repository**. This is done using `git commit`.

These steps take place **locally*. None of these steps have any affect on your `GitHub` repository.

### Secondly, `git push` to the `remote` repository (in this case, your GitHub one).

To get your code from `local` to `remote` repositories, `git push` is used.

1. Check what `remote` repositories are known by your `local` repository: `git remote -v`.
2. If the `GitHub` repository is **not** shown, you'll need to add it: `git remote add <NAME> <URL>`.
3. Because you didn't `git clone`, the two repositories (`local` and `remote`) don't have any commits in common. That's ok; it just means `git` doesn't automatically know where to push your changes, so you'll have to specifiy: `git push <NAME> master:master`. That'll push your `local master` branch to the `<NAME> master` branch.

Comment: @simont--after running git commit what should I do? please help.